How do I add more left to each iteration of my FOR using Django Language Template + HTML?
I'm having problems making a code in HTML + DLT for printing documents (Delivery Note).
What happens is that the customer needs the products to be next to each other.
I will ite the products through For, where the first product would have left:8mm and the second would be added 40mm. However, if there are more than 2 products, the third always overlaps the second!
I would need that with each iteration of my FOR, more LEFT be added to <span>, starting with 8mm and increasing from 40mm to 40mm.
Full code:
<div style="font-family:none;">
    <style>
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Libre+Barcode+39&display=swap');
        @page {margin:0;font-family: Arial !important;}
        html * {font-family: Arial }
        table{border-collapse: collapse;table-layout: fixed}
        .padding-td {padding:0.3cm}
        .check-box {width:0.2cm;height:0.2cm;border:1px solid;margin-right:0.1cm}
        table td{color:#000;border:1px solid;vertical-align: initial;}
        .cell_azul{background: #d8e1f2;font-size: 7pt;}
        .right{text-align: right;}
        .center{text-align: center;}
        .cell_cinza{background: #f5f5f5;height:26px;}
        .cell_branco{background: #fff;}
        .cert{width:1.42cm;height:1.85cm;border:solid 1px}
        .contact-text{margin-left:auto;font-size:14px;margin-top:0.1cm}
        .table-texts{display:flex;flex-direction:row;font-size:13px;height:0.7cm}
        .size-texts {font-size: 10px }
        .absolutes {position: absolute;padding: inherit;text-align: left;font-size: 14px;font-weight: bold}
    </style>
    {% for delivery_note in delivery_notes %}
        <div style="min-width: 21cm;min-height: 29.5cm;background: #fff;padding-top: 5mm;padding-left: 15mm;page-break-after: always;position:relative">

            <!--DESCRIPCIÓN DE HORMIGON-->
            {% with 8 as initial_left %}
            {% for product_note in delivery_note.products_note %}
            {% if forloop.first %}
            <span class="absolutes" style="top:54mm;left: {{ initial_left }}mm;width: 10cm; font-size: 14px;font-weight: bold;">
                {{ product_note.product.name }}
            </span>
            {% else %}
            {% with initial_left|add:forloop.counter0|add:forloop.counter|add:40 as left_addition %}
            <span class="absolutes" style="top:54mm;left: {{ left_addition }}mm;width: 9cm; font-size: 14px;font-weight: bold;">
                    {{ product_note.product.name }}
                </span>
            {% endwith %}
            {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
            {% endwith %}

            <span class="absolutes" style="top:54mm;left: 160mm;font-size: 18px;">{{delivery_note.delivery.VOLUME}}</span>
            <span class="absolutes" style="top:68mm;left: 5mm;">{{'{'|add:'{'|add:delivery_note.delivery.START|add:"|date:shortTime"|add:'}'|add:'}'}}</span>

            <span class="absolutes" style="top:91mm;left: 5mm;">{{'{'|add:'{'|add:delivery_note.delivery.START|add:"|date:dd"|add:'}'|add:'}'}}</span>
            <span class="absolutes" style="top:91mm;left: 27mm;">{{'{'|add:'{'|add:delivery_note.delivery.START|add:"|date:MM"|add:'}'|add:'}'}}</span>
            <span class="absolutes" style="top:91mm;left: 45mm;">{{'{'|add:'{'|add:delivery_note.delivery.START|add:"|date:yyyy"|add:'}'|add:'}'}}</span>
            <span class="absolutes" style="top:91mm;left: 63mm">{% if delivery_note.delivery.lacre != None %}{{delivery_note.delivery.lacre}}{% endif %}</span>
            {% if delivery_note.project.client.erpkey is not None %}
            <span class="absolutes" style="top:91mm; left:80mm">{{delivery_note.project.client.erpkey}}</span>
            {% endif %}
            {% if delivery_note.address.address_erpkey is not None %}
                <span class="absolutes" style="top:91mm; left:95mm">{{delivery_note.address.address_erpkey}}</span>
            {% endif %}
            <span class="absolutes" style="top:91mm; left:110mm">  {% if delivery_note.order.order_number is not None %}{{delivery_note.order.order_number}}{% endif %}</span>

            <!--IDENTIFICACIÓN DE CLIENTE-->
            <span class="absolutes" style="top:111mm;left: 25mm">{% if delivery_note.project.client.name != None %}{{ delivery_note.project.client.name }}{% endif %}</span>
            <span class="absolutes" style="top:111mm;left: 135mm">{% if delivery_note.delivery.structure_type != None %}{{ delivery_note.delivery.structure_type }}{% endif %}</span>
            {% if delivery_note.project.client.document is not None %}
                <span class="absolutes" style="top:118mm; left:25mm">{{delivery_note.project.client.document}}</span>
            {% endif %}
            <span class="absolutes" style="top:129mm;left: 25mm; width: 75mm;">{% if delivery_note.project.address.address_street != None %}{{delivery_note.project.address.address_street}}{% endif %}</span>
            {% if delivery_note.project.client.phone is not None %}
            <span class="absolutes" style="top:129mm; left:135mm">{% if delivery_note.project.client.phone != None %}{{delivery_note.project.client.phone}} {% endif %}</span>
            {% endif %}
            <span class="absolutes" style="top:140mm;left: 25mm; width: 75mm;">{% if delivery_note.project.address.address_full != None %}{{delivery_note.project.address.address_full}}{% endif %}</span>

            <!--DATOS DE CAMIÓN-->
            <span class="absolutes" style="top:200mm;left: 77mm">{% if delivery_note.delivery.vehicle.name != None %}{{delivery_note.delivery.vehicle.name}}{%  endif %}</span>
            <span class="absolutes" style="top:218mm;left: 78mm">{% if delivery_note.delivery.driver.nome != None %}{{delivery_note.delivery.driver.nome}}{%  endif %}</span>
            {% if delivery_note.delivery.driver.document is not None %}
                <span class="absolutes" style="top:213mm; left:110mm">{% if delivery_note.delivery.driver.document != None %}{{delivery_note.delivery.driver.document}} {% endif %}</span>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>

Part of the code:
{% with 8 as initial_left %}             
{% for product_note in delivery_note.products_note %}             
{% if forloop.first %}             
<span class="absolutes" style="top:54mm;left: {{ initial_left }}mm;width: 10cm; font-size: 14px;font-weight: bold;"> {{ product_note.product.name }} </span>             
{% else %}             {
% with initial_left|add:forloop.counter0|add:forloop.counter|add:40 as left_addition %}             <span class="absolutes" style="top:54mm;left: {{ left_addition }}mm;width: 9cm; font-size: 14px;font-weight: bold;"> {{ product_note.product.name }} </span>             
{% endwith %}             
{% endif %}             
{% endfor %}             
{% endwith %}

Image of how it is going at the moment:

I have already tried to create another if to deal with the second specific product, but I was not successful and it would not be good for reading and understanding by my colleagues.
NOTE: I can't use JS :(

Note: each with template tag creates a scope of its own in the template, you can't iteratively update variables you create using the with tag.
